# $rename on embedded documents with DottedFieldName in MongoDB 2.4?

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to upgrade my MongoDB 2.4 database to 2.6. I ran the upgrade check and got a lot of errors telling me that my field names were invalid.

```
Document Error: document is no longer valid in 2.6 because DottedFieldName: my@gmail#com.test.coddington.us is not valid for storage.
```

I'm trying to run the [$rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#rename-a-field-in-an-embedded-document) operation on the document, but I think it's having trouble dealing with the invalid fields. However, the fields got into the document *somehow* so I'm hoping there's a way to reference them now. Here's the command I'm running:

```
db.Activity.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5123b2d879d0cdf12e62da99")}, { $rename: {"my@gmail#com.test.coddington.us": "my@gmail#com#test#coddington#us"} })
```

I thought the problem might be able to be resolved by using `\.` instead of `.` but that didn't make a difference. I also tried referencing the field name's periods by their Unicode representation, `\u002e`. I had no luck with that either.

```
db.Activity.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5123b2d879d0cdf12e62da99")}, { $rename: {"my@gmail#com\u002etest\u002ecoddington\u002eus": "my@gmail#com#test#coddington#us"} })
```

I know that $rename doesn't work on arrays, but this just seems like an embedded document that is hard to properly access.

Does anyone know how I should be accessing this field in order to rename it?

For reference, here's a snippet of the document itself so you can see how it is laid out.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5123b2d879d0cdf12e62da99"),
    "deliveryStatuses": {
        "my@gmail#com.test.coddington.us": "sent"
    },
    "version": 1
}
```

Comment: Your bigger problem is that you're storing dynamic data in your keys.  Don't rename these keys, change your schema to move them into value fields.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I don't really have the ability to change the schema- the developers control the schema, I'm in charge of upgrading the MongoDB installation. I just need to get these keys changed so they're valid. This has been foisted upon me and I'm trying to salvage things the best I can.

Comment: I wonder if I'm going to be stuck using `$set` and `$unset` instead of the `$rename` method. I have a feeling it's going to be hard to get MongoDB to access the field with `$set` as well. Does anyone know if the two methods are comparable performance-wise? Set/unset seems ugly to me so I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain - I also have a MongoDB database with keys with periods in them - it appears that earlier versions of some drivers did not prevent the insertion of what is an illegal key name with periods in them.

The problem is all of the MongoDB tools (or most of them) do not support working with the fields, so it get's kind of painful. I've got two suggestions for you:

1. You could export the collection in question using mongoexport and
   then change the problematic fields within the file. You would them
   use mongoimport to import the data into a new cleaned up collection.
   If the file is small you can use an editor, if it's large you can
   use    something like awk or sed to make the change - the file is
   just text after all.
2. You could write a small snippet of code to iterate over each
   document, modify the field name in question and then save the
   resulting document (with the existing ObjectId) into a new
   collection. Slower but the advantage here is that you can tell with
   arbitrary strings (for example, a variable number of dots within
   each field name). Your choice for coding language but this would be
   straightforward in Python.

In either case, after loading the data into a new collection, you rename the old collection and then rename the new one with the old name, and you should be done.

Agree with @JohnnyHK that you should change your schema long term, but this will at least clean up what you have so you can use it with 2.6 while you working on a schema change.

Comment: That's interesting, John. I've only got about 1500 fields to change, so the mongoexport method might be the way to go on this. I've been assured that our production database does not have this problem and the fields have been sanitized prior. I might throw in the towel and just fix the data outside of Mongo.